# Bootstrap template with Django

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap, web, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a complete skeleton of a website in Bootstrap 3. I am very new to Django (not to Python though). I want to integrate this particular theme and build the backend using Django. I cannot find any website for instructions on this. How can this be done? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to prepare your templates that you do usually.In your settings file, make the following changes.

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    os.path.join(PROJECT_BASE_PATH, 'templates').replace('\\', '/'),
    )

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    )

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = 'media/'

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = TCP + (
'django.core.context_processors.request',
)
```

Change your urls.py file to include the urls for static files. Like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^$',LandingPage.as_view(),name='home'),)+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Place your templates in a templates folder inside your app/project and all the css, js and images inside static folder. Be sure to to include {{STATIC_URL}} before all css,js and image urls inside all the templates. Something like this:

```
<script src="{{STATIC_URL}}js/jquery.js"></script>
```

For more information on handling templates in django, try [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/)

Answer (score 1):

It's easier than you think :)

Look at the [template syntax](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/) and [how to serve static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) (css, js), and you can reuse what you have aldready done

also, look at the [django tutorials](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/)